# Word for silent expression of tickled shock at someone else's outburst

Tags: single-word-requests, emotions

Someone is very upset and making a scene. You have no sympathy. You think the whole situation is very entertaining. The sense of schadenfreude and shock at the improper outburst is strong enough that you can't help but make a face, but you *are* able to remain silent and you do so in order to remain as discreet as possible. You don't necessarily make eye contact with anyone else.

In the following picture, the girl on the right demonstrates this kind of reaction. The girl on the left might not be truly upset, but the depiction is close enough.

Is there a good word for this?

[image: gesture]

Comment: Amused? Nonplussed?

Comment: Can't do one single word... "OMG, I can't believe she's doing that!"

Answer (score 3):

The word "bemused" may fit this context well.

As per Merriam Webster dictionary, the definition of this word is - 
to cause to have feelings of wry or tolerant amusement

Answer (score 2):

A word I learned [here at EL&U is](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130384/describing-not-knowing-what-to-do-as-a-response-to-an-unexpected-event-that-h/130392#130392)...

**[gobsmacked](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gobsmacked)**

> so shocked you cannot speak

coming from the slang word "gob" for "mouth"

It is informal, but a great word.

Comment: ...but I am still looking for that elusive word for "stunned amusement".

Answer (score 0):

***Gasp*** — [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gasp)

> 1. catch one's breath with an open mouth, owing to pain or astonishment.
>      *"a woman gasped in horror at the sight of him"*

[Google Images](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=gasp&lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X) shows some examples.

Comment: Close, but you'll notice none of those pictures depict amusement or a sense of humor.

Comment: @MackTuesday Ah, I noticed that now.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider

***flabbergasted***

Defined in [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flabbergasted) as:

> Adj.   1.  flabbergasted - as if struck dumb with astonishment and surprise; "the flabbergasted aldermen were speechless”

Comment: Although I think a mother would be more likely to be flabbergasted than a sister would.